# How can i enter from keyboard a phrase using an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char, phrase

here's what i understand it would be necessary to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public const int N = 100;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] phrase = new char[N];
            int i=0;
            Console.WriteLine("enter a phrase: ");
            while ((i < N) && (phrase[i] != '.'))
            {
                phrase[i] = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
                i++;
            }
             while(i<N){
                Console.WriteLine(+phrase[i]+"  ");
                i++;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

and also I want to know if there's a way I can enter a phrase without having to press intro for every character I introduce

Comment: ...`Console.ReadLine` gives you an entire line as a `string`, which is what you want.

Comment: So how do I use Console.ReadLine to fill an array of characters?

Comment: If you really **need** an array of characters, use the [`ToCharArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) method. If you just want to represent an ordered collection of characters, use a `string` - it's what it's designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something you can just do this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {           
        Console.WriteLine("enter a phrase: ");
        string phrase = Console.ReadLine();           
        var chars = phrase.ToCharArray();  //If you want it as a char array
 }
```

The `Console.ReadLine()` will read the line until the user hits return/enter and we can store this is the string phrase. If you do want the input in a char array you can use the `.ToCharArray()` function on the string

Comment: And if i wanted to print this array, how would I manage to do so?

Comment: @JordiGarcía you would use  Console.WriteLine(phrase);